# Is there a WYSIWYG editor for MediaWiki that lets me edit rows and columns for a table?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm developing a wiki (based off of MediaWiki and Semantic Mediawiki+), and I'm having some trouble with tables - after making one, I'd like to be able to add another column or row in a WYSIWYG editor, as not all of the users know MediaWiki markup.

Currently, I can't change the # of rows/columns after creating a table through my WYSIWYG editor - is there a fix or another editor to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you can wire up [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) as an editor. This supports table and block manipulation (along with a host of other options). There's even [a page on meta.wikimedia.org about it](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TinyMCE_MW).

Comment: Looking at making a TinyMCE Plugin to parse wiki text. Did you ever find more on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

We use the [official FCK editor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FCKeditor_%28Official%29) which works really well for tables. The only problem is if you then switch back to the default editor - you can get **a lot** of unexpected / not wanted formatting which makes it quite hard to read. But you can always go back (again) to FCK editing.